# How to execute runCommand with Mongoid > v7?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How to run db.runCommand in newer versions of mongoid.

Example:
MyModel.collection.database.command(eval: "db.runCommand ( { compact: 'sessions' } )" )

used to work in older version of mongoid but it now throws "DcSite.collection.database.command(eval: "db.runCommand ( { compact: 'sessions' } )" )" error.

by
TheR

Comment: What version of Mongoid are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `command` method directly. For example:

```rb
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
end
Band.create!
Band.collection.database.command(compact: "bands")
```

The `command` method executes a `runCommand` under the hood, and parses the given hash to send to the database.

Here are the docs on the `command` method: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ruby-driver/master/api/Mongo/Database.html#command-instance_method